# Android: How do I remove a request with LocationRequest?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

Im using Google Play Services, Fused Location Provider and LocationRequest to get the current location.

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1); 
mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
```

I would like to know how do I go about cancelling a request in progress? As stated by documentation when I call setNumUpdates() and pass 1, I must set an expiration which is fine while the app is running but what if I go to paused state? How can I explicitly cancel the request as the docs mention as soon as paused state occurs?

Thanks for reading

Comment: you mean so you stop getting location updates?

Comment: `mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);`

Comment: @tyczj Yes and lets say I request my current location which can take some time, I want to cancel the request in progress as soon as pause state occurs

Comment: @johncarter just remove location updates like Leo said but make sure to start them again in onResume

Comment: @LeoLandau will that cancel the current request is well?

Comment: removing location updates basically removes the callback to where you created it. you might also want to call disconnect on the location client

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling mGoogleApiClient.connect(); at onStart(), do that on onCreate(), and setNumUpdates will called only once.

Answer (score 1):

Just stop it like this, using the instance of your

```
fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
```

See the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates